# Is there a way exclude few subscription on IAM role assignment in Management group?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an Azure Management Group X with 200 subscriptions. Is there a way I can give a role assignment to App in scope X by excluding particular 15 subscriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible give a role assignment to App in scope X by excluding particular few subscriptions.

Once you assigned scope of managed group it will include all the subscription there won’t be option filter out the subscription.

[image]

To achieve your requirement, you can create sub manage group under root manage group add specific subscription in sub manage group that you want.

Then add that sub manage group in the scope.

You can follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview) to understand the hierarchy of management group.